# The Google Sheets script I'm using is copying a named Range, but to the wrong column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a modified Google Sheets script I found on here to keep a named range synced across two tabs of a document. However, when an edit happens, it just copies the named range ("Attendance") from Sheet2 to the first column of Sheet1, as opposed to the same position in Sheet1. (Basically, the range it's copying from in Sheet2 is Column I, but it copies into Column A in Sheet1, overwriting the data there.)

What can I add so it goes to the right place?

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "1SrT3N_DI1vLeh-ACisZgREA5gMPjAWQu8edQtWXC3lM";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Sheet2";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "1SrT3N_DI1vLeh-ACisZgREA5gMPjAWQu8edQtWXC3lM";
var targetWorksheetName = "Sheet1";

function onEdit(e) {
var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("Attendance");


var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation) to retrieve the A1 notation of the named range, and use it for your target range.

So, replace this:

```
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns());
```

With this:

```
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(thisData.getA1Notation());
```

#### Notes:

- If you want to copy the range (formatting included) and not just the values, and if both ranges are on the same spreadsheet, use [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) instead of `setValues`.
- If the spreadsheet/s you are working is not the container of your script, this script might need authorization, in which case I'd suggest you to [install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) the `onEdit` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
const vA=thisData.getValues();
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 2, vA.length, vA[0].length);
```

Comment: That results in a "Exception: The number of columns in the range must be at least 1." error message

Answer (score 0):

This is because your getRange is set to Row 1, Column 1 hence when you change it to desired row and column you will get the data placed in specified row and column

```
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 9, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
```

Hope this solves your issue.